# question about prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Prove that for all odd prime numbers $p_1$ and $p_2$, there exist prime numbers(exclude 2) $p_3$ and $p_4$ such that $$p_3 + p_4 = p_1 + p_2 + 2.$$

Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If this is true then the Goldbach conjecture is true.  It is famous, and unproved.

Comment: Start with 2+2=4.  Then, by induction, every even number greater than two is the sum of two prime numbers.

Comment: Well prove it then.

Answer (score 11):

For $p_1=2,p_2=7$, we have $p_1+p_2+2=11$, but there are no pairs of primes $(p_3,p_4)$ such that $$11=p_3+p_4.$$

Comment: Ah damn I forgot to exclude 2. Respect.

Comment: It's better to light a candle than to curse the darkness, and it's better to [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1517556/edit) your question than to lament on what you should have said in the first place.